# Spring Cloud Contract producer cannot send message

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms, spring-cloud-contract

I'm trying to incorporate Spring Cloud Contract into an existing project.  I've had some success with REST but I'm struggling to set up the messaging side.

Thus far I've set up a contract on the producer, which does produce a test in target/generated-test-sources/contracts.  I've also set up a base class for the test.

I can't get past this error:

> 2017-09-08 17:10:51.759 ERROR -  --[]- [           main] o.s.c.c.v.m.stream.StreamStubMessages    : Exception took place while trying to resolve the destination. Will assume the name [invites]
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.ChannelBindingServiceProperties' available
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1093)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamStubMessages.resolvedDestination(StreamStubMessages.java:86)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamStubMessages.receive(StreamStubMessages.java:73)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamStubMessages.receive(StreamStubMessages.java:110)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.stream.StreamStubMessages.receive(StreamStubMessages.java:36)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.messaging.internal.ContractVerifierMessaging.receive(ContractVerifierMessaging.java:40)
>           at org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.tests.email.MessagingTest.validate_invitedContract(MessagingTest.java:27)

and later

> 2017-09-08 17:10:51.759 ERROR -  --[]- [           main] o.s.c.c.v.m.stream.StreamStubMessages    : Exception occurred while trying to read a message from  a channel with name [invites]
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'invites' available
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:687)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1207)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)

My application.yml file under src/test/resources:

`spring:
    cloud:
      stream:
        bindings:
          output:
            content-type: application/json
            destination: invites`

I have the following dependencies:

```
`
    <!-- Spring Cloud Contract Deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- END SCC Deps -->`
```

I've combed through the docs, watched Marcin's talk and looked through the samples for Spring Cloud Contract but I'm stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi! Can you try to use the release train to manage dependencies? Also ensure that you have the @EnableBindings annotation. Also it would be great to see your sample published somewhere on github. It will be easier to help you.

Comment: Hi Marcin.  Using the release train has resolved the problem.  Thank you!

Comment: Cool, I've added my answer. Could you please mark it as the appropriate one?

Comment: Sorry Marcin, I spoke too soon.  I've created a demo project @ https://github.com/jswaff/scc-demo.  I'm sure I'm missing something simple but I can't put my finger on it.  Would you mind having a look?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the missing pieces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First issue:

Please use the release train. In the release train, we know that there are no invalid dependencies.

### Second issue:

You don't have the `@EnableBinding(Source.class)` annotation. That's why Stream doesn't know how to bind to the `output` channel.

If you go to the Spring Cloud Contract samples you'll notice this line on the main application class (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples/blob/master/producer/src/main/java/com/example/ProducerApplication.java#L9). After I've added this line to your code, the context started but the tests failed cause the message wasn't sent.